# How to determine/calculate where the Y axis tick marks are being plotted in CorePlot?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I'm working with CorePlot to generate a bar graph with horizontal bars (CPTXYGraph and CPTBarPlot).

There are only 10 bars being plotted at any given time, but the labels for them are arbitrarily long. As a result of that the Y axis labels rotation is set to  0.5. For the longest labels there are clipping issues with the label going outside of the left and/or bottom of the plot area.

I've fixed this in the X direction by determining the width of the longest label (as rendered in the appropriate font) and rotated the appropriate way to set the left padding in the plotAreaFrame.

Due to the rotation of the labels, if the plot at the bottom of the graph has a long name it can still extend off the bottom edge of the graph and get clipped there.

I know how tall vertically the rotated label is, but where I'm stuck is trying to determine where in the plot area the axis label is being plotted so that I can determine how much bottom padding is required.

I'm not sure if I should be trying to determine how tall the X axis label section is and then subdividing the remaining height to determine where the ticks should fall, or if there's some other better way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are methods that allow you to convert a point from the plot space coordinate system to the view coordinate system. I've ended up solving the problem with code like the following:

```
// Tell the graph to lay itself out if it needs to. 
[self.graph layoutIfNeeded];

// Create a point that represents 0,1 as plotted on the graph.
NSDecimal plotPoint[2];
plotPoint[CPTCoordinateX] = CPTDecimalFromInt (0);
plotPoint[CPTCoordinateY] = CPTDecimalFromInt (1);

// Convert that point from the plot coordinate system to the view coordinate system
CGPoint point = [self.graph.defaultPlotSpace plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint: plotPoint];

// If the difference between the height of the rotated label and the position that it 
// will be plotted at is at least the bottom padding, then the height is too large,
// so fix the padding.
if (labelHeight - point.y >= self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom)
    [self.graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom: (labelHeight - point.y)];
```

My graphs have a default bottom padding already set as a minimum, allowing this code to bump it up if there isn't enough already.

Answer (score 0):

The label is offset from end of the nearest tick mark by the `labelOffset`. The position of the end of the tick mark depends on the `tickDirection`, `tickLabelDirection`, and `majorTickLength`.

Comment: That looks like it tells me how far horizontally from the Y axis line the label will be plotted. Is there a way to determine it's vertical offset from the bottom of the plot area?